# \ref with the counter value

Tags: cross-referencing

Is there some package providing a simple user interface to return the counter value (numeric, not the formatted cross-reference, as `\ref` does) of a label? It seems neither `zref`, not `refcount`, nor `cleveref`, among others, provide it. `cleveref` saves the counter value to the `aux` file, but I couldn't find in the docs a macro to retrieve it (something like, say, `\numbercref`), even if internally there is a `\cref@getcounter` for that.

Please, note I'm not asking how to do it, just if there is a package with a simple *user* interface.

Comment: For more complex problems, zref is the better way to go, I think

Comment: One 'disadvantage' with `zref` is that it is necessary to use `\zlabel` -- i.e. `zref` does not hook into `\label` as `cleveref` does -- the `\zlabel` must be specified in addition to `\label`

Comment: I don't understand why you say [`refcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/refcount) doesn't provide this. Can you explain and/or provide an example as to why you say this?

Comment: Because its manual states "If the reference does not contain a number, assignments to a counter will fail of course" :-). And references can be anything, like "(m)", "V.b.6" or "Second".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have written `crossreftools` about one year ago, this package extracts information from `cleveref` labels with `\crtcrefnumber`, this holds the number of the counter, using the special way how `cleveref` stores the information in its labels.

Traditional labels do not support this, since those labels apply `\thefoo`, meaning that something like `\renewcommand{\thefoo}{\arabic{chapter}.\Roman{section}.\Alph{foo}}` will store `4.II.C`, for example. This way `\crtrefnumber` will report the usual reference value but not the counter value of `foo`, `3` in the above example.

Most `\crt...` macros are expandable.

The `zref` package is very sophisticated, but it does not provide means to store the counter value -- the counter name is quite easy to catch, by loading the  `counter` module of zref, see a possible solution with `zref` at the end, however.

In order to achieve this a new property must be defined, with `\zref@newprop` and later added to the main property list with `\zref@addprop`.

In total, `crossreftools` is not invasive as it just reevaluates the already stored label macros, whereas the second solution changes `\refstepcounter` (marginally, however). If more information is to be stored with within labels, `zref` is most likely the better way to pursue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\begin{document}

See \crtrefnumber{foosec} or \crtcrefnumber{foosec}

\chapter{Foo}

\setcounter{section}{99}

\section{A foo section} \label{foosec}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

Here is version with `zref`, that stores the name of the last counter being used in `\refstepcounter` and extracts the value with `\zlabels` then.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[user,counter]{zref}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\originalrefstepcounter\refstepcounter%
  \renewcommand{\refstepcounter}[1]{%
    \xdef\@@lastrefsteppedcounter{#1}%
    \originalrefstepcounter{#1}%
  }
}

\zref@newprop{value}[-100000]{\number\value{\@@lastrefsteppedcounter}}
\zref@addprop{main}{value}
\newcommand{\counterref}[1]{%
  \zref@extract{#1}{value}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\counterwithin{equation}{chapter}

% some helper macros in order to simplify demonstration of counter values

\newcommand{\foosectionnumber}{100}
\newcommand{\foosubsectionnumber}{20}
\newcommand{\foosubsubsectionnumber}{44}
\newcommand{\einsteinnumber}{1905}

\newcommand{\foofigurenumber}{2018}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tableentryline}[2]{%
  \tabularnewline
  #1 & #2 & \crtrefnumber{#1} & \crtcrefnumber{#1} & \counterref{#1} \tabularnewline
  \tabularnewline
  \hline
} 

\begin{tabular}{lllll}
label & Expected value & \verb!\crtrefnumber! & \verb!\crtcrefnumber! & \verb!\counterref! \tabularnewline
  \hline
  \tableentryline{foosec}{\foosectionnumber} 
  \tableentryline{foosubsec}{\foosubsectionnumber} 
  \tableentryline{foosubsubsec}{\foosubsubsectionnumber} 
  \tableentryline{einstein}{\einsteinnumber}
  \tableentryline{foofigure}{\foofigurenumber}
\end{tabular}


\chapter{Foo}

\setcounter{equation}{\numexpr\einsteinnumber-1}

\setcounter{section}{\numexpr\foosectionnumber-1}

\setcounter{figure}{\numexpr\foofigurenumber-1}


\section{A foo section} \label{foosec}\zlabel{foosec}

\setcounter{subsection}{\numexpr\foosubsectionnumber-1}
\subsection{A foo subsection} \label{foosubsec} \zlabel{foosubsec}

\setcounter{subsubsection}{\numexpr\foosubsubsectionnumber-1}

\subsubsection{A foo subsubsection} \label{foosubsubsec} \zlabel{foosubsubsec}

\begin{equation}
  E= mc^{2} \label{einstein} \zlabel{einstein}
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{foofigure} \label{foofigure} \zlabel{foofigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update again**

Something like (see Javier Bezos' comment below)

`\setcounter{foo}{\crtcrefnumber{foostuff}}`

will fail since `\crtcrefnumber` reports `[UNDEFINED]` in the beginning, i.e. the first run. This breaks `\setcounter` of course

Therefore I have added a new macro that is designed for a 'safe' counter value, i.e. 
`\crtcrefcountervalue` that reports the content of `\crtcrefundefinedcountervalue`, being 1977 (the year TeX was invented ;-)).

I added this code to the package (without the `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair of course) and will uploaded a new version of `crossreftools` to CTAN.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\crt@crefundefinedcountervalue}{1977}
\newcommand{\crtrefundefinedcountervalue}[1]{\renewcommand{\crt@refundefinedcountervalue}{#1}}


\newcommand{\crtcrefcountervalue}[1]{%
  \crtcrefifundefinedlabel{#1}{%
    \crt@crefundefinedcountervalue%
  }{%
    \crtcrefnumber{#1}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

**Update 2019/01/06  21:04 (CET)**

`crossreftools v0.9` is available on TeXLive (and most likely on MikTeX as well...)

Comment: See also `xassoccnt` and `\RegisterPreLabelHook{zlabel}` such that `\label` produces both the orginal label and does call `\zlabel` as well

Comment: `\crtcrefnumber` is (almost) what I was looking for (no @'s at all), but it fails with something like `\setcounter{subsection}{\crtcrefnumber{foosec}}` (the first run). Fortunately, with `\crtrefundefinedtext{0}` everything is fine.

Comment: @JavierBezos: Ah yes, I remember there was an issue with `\setcounter` and `\crt...` macros. I forgot to pursue. I will investigate and upload a new version. Thanks for keeping me informed

Comment: @JavierBezos: I tracked the issue down to `\crtcrefextract` that reports `[UNDEFINED]` during the first run of LaTeX etc. This is not really a bug, but by design. Therefore, in order to provide a calculable return value for counters, I added `\crtcrefcountervalue` that yields `1977` in case of undefined references... That value can be change, of course. I will upload `crossreftools` v.0.8 in a few minutes. In the mean time, you can grab the few lines at the end of my answer

Comment: @JavierBezos: `crossreftools` uploaded ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Actually, `\crtrefundefinedtext{0}` worked for me, but an out-of-the-box solution (so that it "just works") is better.

Comment: @JavierBezos: Well, as I said, it is uploaded and should be available soon on CTAN and MikTeX/TeXLive. I provided in `crossreftools` basically any command with a non - `@` - wrapper, such that they can occur on document level without requiring `\makeatletter...\makeatother` all the time right from the start such that non-package-authors can use it without much additional tedious writing